# how to run a java application in a local area network

Tags: java, lan

I've already finished my application and I've also converted my code into a runnable jar file and convert it to a .exe. My question is how can I configure my application so I can use it in our local area network?

Say for example, I can use one of our station to encode or update some data then the data will be save into our server and if i want i can also call those data from another station.  To clarify, I  want to deploy my application from the server to other computers so that they can run the application locally (My application is a swing application).  Do I need to specify the path on which the data are to be save and if so who do I execute this? Can you give me a tip on how to achieve this goal?

Comment: If you need only to reach common stored files, you need to set the correct path (maybe in a virtual o convided harddisk, or something similar).

If you need that each instance of your program talk with the other it's a bit more difficult (yet not impossible). You can communicate via TPC Socket.

Merging the two solutions you can also create a server program that handles the local stored files and the instance of the program communicate with it to modify them. This can preserve security access to the file that not need to be condivided on the net. You can have also control on the received files

Comment: Do you know of any site that give tutorials on how to achieved this goal.  I hope you'll share it with me, thanks.

Comment: search here in stackoverflow, surely you find many questions like your, or just surf with google, you find many tutorials of basic action.
If you want to learn well you should buy a book and start from the theory, this is the best way to do.

if you can't find something interesting, just ask on stackoverflow and you will be aswered ;)